Use jersey app resource "offline in a webapp" without a servlet request?
I have Tomcat10 JerseyRest+JacksonJson webapp using a @Provider ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> to initialize an ObjectMapper. It gets used by the jackson's internal json writers.
Normal http requests go through a jersey servlet OrderService resource handler, it's easy to use @Context private Providers providers injection and access a preconfigured jackson ObjectMapper instance.
Question: How do I access jersey-jackson "offline" such as a backend scheduled thread, no http requests involved? I would like to reuse ObjectMapper and maybe other things as well.
My current solution is public static MyApplication.getObjectMapper(Providers providers) getter works even with a null argument, it uses a singleton hack in MapperContextResolver.java class.
Or is this solution just fine keep things simple and a global static singleton for ObjectMapper instance. I don't plan to modify OM config after an initialization.
Example webapp files:

https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager2/blob/main/example_webapp/src/test/rest/MyApplication.java
https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager2/blob/main/example_webapp/src/test/rest/MapperContextResolver.java
https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager2/blob/main/example_webapp/src/test/rest/OrderService.java


Can you pass the Jersey InjectionManager to the background thread? Then you can just use injectionManager.getInstance(Providers.class) to get the providers.

@jan.supol I tried to study this but could not find a way to get InjectionManager instance InjectionManager im = InjectionManagerProvider.getInjectionManager(feature). Logical place would be MyApplication extends ResourceConfig implementation to get an instance and keep it static for "offline" users.

You should be able to inject InjectionManager into the Application subclass

@jan.supol Need to study this more, @Inject InjectionManager im  is NULL in a jersey application ... I do inherit ResourceConfig but that should not make a difference.
https://github.com/Murmur/ScopedEntityManager2/blob/main/example_webapp/src/test/rest/MyApplication.java

ok, try to wrap the AbstractBinder registration into a Feature and get the InjectionManager from the FeatureContext: register(new Feature() { public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) { InjectionManager injectionManager = InjectionManagerProvider.getInjectionManager(context); context.register(new AbstractBinder() {...}}})
